# MVC4: Determine current user access from ControllerName and ActionName

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking at creating a security trimmed MenuLinks in my current site and wonder what the easiest method in MVC4 is to determine if the current user has access to a given Controller and Action using only the controller name and action name.

I've come across a couple of question\answers with broken links to "solutions" and a couple that target previous versions of MVC and just seem quite complicated. I suppose if I have to I'll create instances of the given controller, get the authorize attributes then manually do the security checks, but I was really hoping there might be an easier way in MVC4! :)

Essentially I'm looking for an equivalent to or suggestions on to how to implement "`UserHasAccessTo`" in the following:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString SecurityTrimmedActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
    {
        if(UserHasAccessTo(actionName, controllerName))
            return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName);
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: I would keep a dictionary of rules in an abstract SecureController and I would derive each controller from the SecureController. By this way rules of Access will be available at all controllers & OnAuthorize method of SecureController will grant access based on rules. You can create dictionary of Lambda expressions that is easy to read & invoke.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a easy and secure way

1. Define an attribute that inherits from AuthorizeAttribute and override AuthorizeCore

   ```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method,
                            Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
       internal sealed class MyAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
       {
           protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
           {
               var username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;

               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
                   return false;

               return UserHasAccessTo(username, ActionName, ControllerName);
           }

           public bool ActionName { get; set; }

           public bool ControllerName { get; set; }
       }
   ```
2. override HandleUnauthorizedRequest

   ```
   protected override void 
                HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   {
       filterContext.Result = string.Empty;
   }
   ```
3. Apply the attribute to your methods or classes

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help...   I know how to implement a custom AuthorizeAttribute. What I'm asking is how I can check in an HtmlHelper extension (or elsewhere) whether the current user has access to a given Controller\Action given the name of said controller and action...